# What is microstructure in image processing

Tags: image-processing

In image processing to be able to represent an image effectively, there are several methods. I am reading a paper about how one can represent an image semantically using the integration of low-level features. What I am not sure about the purpose of using **microstructures** in the below sentence [in this paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8704206/):

> CMSD represents high-level semantics by identifying **microstructures**
> via establishing correlations between texture orientation, color, and
> intensity features.

This is not the only paper using this term.

I think is that **microstructure**, like micro-color and/or micro-maps, is to extract features and then integrating them into one feature set. Could anyone explain what microstructures like micro-color are in image processing and why they are called **micro**?

Comment: I know what microstructure is, but it’s not an image processing term. It is literally the microscopic structure in materials, the structure you can only discern under a microscope. Who knows what the authors of that bit of text were thinking when they used that term. Maybe a reference to the original text could help?

Comment: @CrisLuengo, this is the link to the original paper: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8704206/

Comment: This is the mention of the term in their literature review: “to represent image features by microstructures [35].” There’s a copy of that paper [here](http://www4.comp.polyu.edu.hk/~cslzhang/paper/PR_MSD.pdf). This paper invents the term “microstructure” to mean small portions of a texture that can be described. It is certainly not a common term, and the paper you found should have introduced and explained the term, as well as all the other “micro-” things they make up. It looks to me they took this term and went a little crazy with it.